# how can i fill v accordion dynamically based on id of the parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, accordion

I m using v accordion i want to fill the data dynamically inside it based on the id of the parent accordion. my problem is that it shows the parent accordion on loading but as soon as i click on it, it removes all the parent accordion just diaplying the child accordion of the one that is clicked

index.html

```
        <v-pane id="{{ ::pane.pid }}" ng-repeat="pane in panesC" expanded="pane.isExpanded" ng-click="displaytask(pane.pid)"'>
          <v-pane-header id="{{ ::pane.pid }}-header" aria-controls="{{ ::pane.pid }}-header">
            <h5>{{ ::pane.projectname }}</h5>
          </v-pane-header>

          <v-pane-content id="{{ ::pane.pid }}-content" aria-labelledby="{{ ::pane.pid }}-content">
            <p>{{ ::pane.projectdesc }}

            </p>

            <v-accordion id="nestedAccordionA" >
              <v-pane id="{{ ::subpane.tid }}" ng-repeat="subpane in pane.subpanes" ng-disabled="subpane.isDisabled">
                <v-pane-header id="{{ ::subpane.tid }}-header" aria-controls="{{ ::subpane.tid }}-header">
                  <h5>{{ ::subpane.taskname }}</h5>
                </v-pane-header>
                <v-pane-content id="{{ ::subpane.tid }}-content" aria-labelledby="{{ ::subpane.tid }}-content">
                  <p>{{ ::subpane.taskname }}</p>
                </v-pane-content>
              </v-pane>
            </v-accordion>
          </v-pane-content>
        </v-pane>

      </v-accordion>
```

app.js

```
.controller('MainController', function ($scope, $http) 
 {
  $scope.panesC= [{ subpanes:[] }];

  $scope.display = function()
  {  
      $http.get('displayproject')
      .success(function (data, status, headers, config)
       {
          $scope.panesC=data;
        });         
  }
    $scope.display();

    $scope.displaytask = function(pid)
    {
        $http({
            method : "POST",
            url : "displaytask",
            data : pid,
        })
        .success(function(response)
        {
             $scope.panesC=[{subpanes:response}];
        });
    };

      $scope.expandCallback = function (index, id) {
            console.log('expand:', index, id);
          };

          $scope.collapseCallback = function (index, id) {
            console.log('collapse:', index, id);
          };

          $scope.$on('accordionA:onReady', function () {
            console.log('accordionA is ready!');
          });
```

link

http://angular-js.in/v-accordion/